# Excel VBA working code suddenly has "type mismatch" error today

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

The below code has been running perfectly for 6 months now and has not been altered (to my knowledge). Today i run the code and get Run-time error 13 Type Mismatch. The line of code which gets the error is pointed out by 
(TYPE MISMATCH --------> )
Please help.

```
Sub ADULTClearAndPaste()

Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Members to cut & past")
Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT Sign On Sheet")

Program = 9
ATP = 10
FIFO = 7
LastName = 2
FirstName = 3
Sh2.Select
For Each cell In Sh2.Range("B1:F756")
If cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite Then
   cell.ClearContents
End If
    Next


lr = Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
W = 7
For r = 2 To lr

TYPE MISMATCH -------->  If Sh1.Range("U" & r).Value = "White" Then 
    Sh2.Cells(W, 2).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, Program).Value
    Sh2.Cells(W, 3).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, ATP).Value
    Sh2.Cells(W, 4).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, FIFO).Value
    Sh2.Cells(W, 5).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, LastName).Value
    Sh2.Cells(W, 6).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, FirstName).Value
    W = W + 1
End If

Next r
```

Comment: check your column U for cells that have errors.

Comment: Already checked, and checked format of cells aswel

Comment: What is the value or r when the error is thrown? What is the value in that cell at the time?

Comment: @NickPeranzi there was a value all the way down on row 376 this didn't match my vlookup. thanks

Comment: Excellent, glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the cell has an error within its value or contains a non-string. The below code should eliminate your error:

```
Sub ADULTClearAndPaste()

Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
Dim Sh1 as Worksheet, Sh2 as Worksheet
Dim StrVal as String
Dim Program as Integer, ATP as Integer, FIFO as Integer, LastName as Integer, FirstName as Integer
Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Members to cut & past")
Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT Sign On Sheet")

Program = 9
ATP = 10
FIFO = 7
LastName = 2
FirstName = 3

For Each cell In Sh2.Range("B1:F756")
    If cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite Then
       cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next


lr = Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
W = 7
For r = 2 To lr

    On Error Resume Next
    StrVal = vbNullString
    StrVal = Sh1.Range("U" & r).Value
    On Error GoTo 0 'Or implement proper error handling
    If StrVal = "White" Then 
        Sh2.Cells(W, 2).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, Program).Value
        Sh2.Cells(W, 3).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, ATP).Value
        Sh2.Cells(W, 4).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, FIFO).Value
        Sh2.Cells(W, 5).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, LastName).Value
        Sh2.Cells(W, 6).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, FirstName).Value
        W = W + 1
    End If

Next r

End Sub
```

The above code should eliminate your error but will not address the root cause of your issue. The below code will not only eliminate your error but will also display a message box with any error rows.

```
Sub ADULTClearAndPaste()

Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
Dim Sh1 as Worksheet, Sh2 as Worksheet
Dim StrVal as String, StrOutput as String
Dim Program as Integer, ATP as Integer, FIFO as Integer, LastName as Integer, FirstName as Integer
Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Members to cut & past")
Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT Sign On Sheet")

Program = 9
ATP = 10
FIFO = 7
LastName = 2
FirstName = 3

For Each cell In Sh2.Range("B1:F756")
    If cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite Then
       cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next


lr = Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
W = 7
For r = 2 To lr

    On Error Resume Next
    If IsError(Sh1.Range("U" & r).Value) Then
        'There is an error with the value. Log it for output.
        If StrOutput = vbNullString Then 
            StrOutput = "Errors encountered with the following rows: " & r
        Else
            StrOutput = StrOutput & ", " & r
        End If
    Else
        'Execute your code
        StrVal = vbNullString
        StrVal = Sh1.Range("U" & r).Value
        On Error GoTo 0 'Or implement proper error handling
        If StrVal = "White" Then 
            Sh2.Cells(W, 2).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, Program).Value
            Sh2.Cells(W, 3).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, ATP).Value
            Sh2.Cells(W, 4).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, FIFO).Value
            Sh2.Cells(W, 5).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, LastName).Value
            Sh2.Cells(W, 6).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, FirstName).Value
            W = W + 1
        End If
    End If

Next r

'Display success or error message
If StrOutput <> vbNullString Then
    MsgBox StrOutput, vbCritical
Else
    MsgBox "Done!"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @DanDonoghue - I was confused with an issue I experienced recently with other variable types throwing an error when attempting to load blank values. I removed the point about it being empty; regardless, I still believe OP's issue will be solved through my answer.

Comment: Be keen to find out what the issue actually is, at least your error logging will show the row for analysis :). Side note, awesome solution on MultipleRadarCharts ;)

Comment: Agreed - I was unable to replicate OP's issue in my testing except by storing an error value in the cell, which OP believes is not the case. Thanks for the kudos :)

Comment: SOLVED thanks @NickPeranzi my vlookup in column "U" row 376 didnt match the requirements and was returning NA. My original code is now working. Do you advise that I still amend my code with the changes you provided?

Comment: @BradleyJones Short answer: yes. Long answer: personally, I prefer to handle errors cleanly and display more informative error messages than the debug messages provided by VBA execution errors. Many other VBA devs feel the same, but if you are the only user and/or prefer to have the default error messages, you can leave it.

Comment: Will start using it then. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this missing an "e" on the end of the sheet name?

```
Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Members to cut & past")
```

Seems so being that the first time you try and use the sheet is when it errors

Edit: My bad, you are using it here without error:

```
lr = Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

Your code works for me, possible dead reference? check for "missing" in tools / references in the VBE.